# How to work on a project with a team on Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, github

So i am developing Java applications in Eclipse. Until now i did this on my own, but recently one friend of mine had an awesome idea for an application and suggested we both work at it so we need to share the project files. I've searched the web and found something about using git trough the EGit plugin. The problem is that i don't really understand how this really works.

Are there any other ways to make this happen? (as i'm not ready to upgrade my git for private repositories since i don't understand how this stuff work)

Comment: You don't understand the role and importance of `git`, or you do understand why `git` is useful, but you don't master using it thru `egit` plugin for Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to use Git and using GitHub as the platform is arguably the best way to collaborate then. The easiest way to start is learning Git from the command line. Once you have an idea how that works it is usually very easy to figure out how the plugin (in your case EGit) works.

Check out the [Git reference](http://gitref.org/) and GitHubs awesome [interactive tutorial for learning Git](http://try.github.com/levels/1/challenges/1).

Comment: So i guess, it comes to learn git. Well, i'm always open to new things.

Answer (score 0):

So you have Git installed on your personal computer and you want to share the source with your friend so you can both work on it?

I see two option.

## 1 Open up your computer so that your friend can access it directly off your computer, probably not the best idea.

## 2 Sign up for a repository on the web, maybe GitHub?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I thought forums where used to transport answers. Should I email him directly?

Answer (score 0):

Just get a SVN repository or GIT and the Eclipse [SVN plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) . You can up and download Code then and if your mate altered a file at the same time than you, you will be prompted to MERGE the file - eclipse will do most work just use svn for the beginning.

Comment: I do recommend using `git` for a new project, but not `svn`; leave `svn` to old legacy projects.

Comment: You are right but svn is faster to set up for greenhorns^^ and as it is a project between two people it wouldn't make a huge difference

Comment: You just made me curious. What is the best option for a project shared between  more than 2 people.

Comment: @Romeo well for small group projects svn would be just fine too but if you work on a big project the best choice would be git or Mercurial because they are designed for this application